# Rails 3: fields_for partial renders twice, once normally and once as escaped output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, partial-views, fields-for

Trying to render a partial using a fields_for block.  The partial renders the form fields fine, but then renders the output *again* as escaped HTML.  The code to call the partial is here (haml):

```
= fields_for "advertisement[versions_attributes][#{@advertisement.versions.size-1}]".to_sym, @version do |version_fields|
  = render :partial => 'advertisement_versions/fields', :locals => {:f => version_fields}
```

I've tried using - fields_for and - render, but with no luck. - fields_for won't render the partial, and - render produces the same problem.

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve with messy `advertisement[versions_attributes][#{@advertisement.versions.size-1}]".to_sym`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= fields_for "advertisement[versions_attributes][#{@advertisement.versions.size-1}]".to_sym, @version do |version_fields|
  = render :partial => 'advertisement_versions/fields', :f => version_fields
```

If I'm not wrong you can also omit `:partial =>` and just do

```
= render 'advertisement_versions/fields', :f => version_fields
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you already tried, but I had the same problem (rendering the output again as escaped HTML) with rails 2.3.14. Fixing

```
= fields_for .....
```

with

```
- fields_for .....
```

solved it for me.